# Firewatir: Error when installing Firewatir on Windows

Tags: automated-tests, watir, firewatir

I am trying to install Firewatir on my PC (its OS is Windows). I have installed the jssh and test it. It is properly installed.

After that, I tried to install the firewatir gem. So I ran this command:

> gem install firewatir

Then, I got this error:

> **ERROR: While executing gem ... (RunTimeError)**
>
> ```
>     Error installing firewatir:
>
>          firewatir requires commonwatir = 1.6.5
> ```

Does that mean I have to install commonwatir first? When I tried to install commonwatir, I got similar error. But this time, the commonwatir required user-choices. And now, it becomes a long dependence chain of installation.

Answer (score 1):

[Watir installation](http://watir.com/installation/) page says all you need to do is

```
gem install watir
```

Firewatir is part of Watir.

Comment: I tried to install watir and an error occurred:
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Error installing watir:
        commonwatir requires user-choices (>= 0, runtime)

I think I know the problem. It is because of the firewall and there is a thread in stackoverflow that discussed about this.

Btw, thank you for your answer :).

Comment: That is correct. The problem is that there are a whole chain of gems that you need to install.